# Get filepath of file in Finder

Tags: applescript, filepath, finder

I want to get the filepath of the front file in the Finder, such as `/Users/user/Downloads/file.png` and I am very confused with the way `macOS` and AppleScript handle file paths, POSIX with slashes and natively with colons. I tried both of these:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set temp to selection
    repeat with i from 1 to length of temp
        set the_item to item i of temp
        
        set item_posix to the_item as POSIX file
        set the_result to POSIX path of item_posix -- returns only the file's name and extension
        
        return get the path of the_item -- returns an error
    end repeat
end tell
```

I once succeeded and it was so convoluted with `as file` and `as alias` that I can't remember how it worked.

How can I get the filepath of the front file in the Finder?

**Update**: I'm interested in a single path for the sake of the syntax and I can handle multiple paths with a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the **inuxmint-20-cinnamon-64bit.iso** *files* selected in the **Downloads** *folders* in **Finder**, here are some examples:

**This command:**

```
tell application "Finder" to get selection
```

**Result:**

```
--> {document file "linuxmint-20-cinnamon-64bit.iso" of folder "Downloads" of folder "me" of folder "Users" of startup disk}
```

**This command:**

```
tell application "Finder" to get selection as alias
```

**Result:**

```
-> {alias "Macintosh HD:Users:me:Downloads:linuxmint-20-cinnamon-64bit.iso"}
```

**This command:**

```
tell application "Finder" to set aliasItemName to selection as alias
```

**Result:**

```
--> {alias "Macintosh HD:Users:me:Downloads:linuxmint-20-cinnamon-64bit.iso"}
```

**These commands:**

```
set posixPathName to POSIX path of aliasItemName
return posixPathName
```

**Result:**

```
"/Users/me/Downloads/linuxmint-20-cinnamon-64bit.iso"
```

Note that `set posixPathName to POSIX path of aliasItemName` is done outside of the context of **Finder** as it does not understand `POSIX path` as it's a part of **Standard Additions**, not **Finder**.

Comment: `POSIX file` is from Standard Additions, but `POSIX path` is a property of an alias.

Comment: See the AppleScript Language Guide for the [alias class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_classes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH1g-SW3).  A conversion isn't necessary, the `POSIX path` property of the alias is text - the properties of a `POSIX file` are inherited from a file or alias.

Comment: Please consider that `tell application "Finder" to get selection as alias` throws an error if multiple items are selected, You have to write `tell application "Finder" to get selection as alias list`

Answer (score 3):

In Finder the `selection` property returns **always** a list of Finder file specifiers or an empty list.

The easiest way using your syntax is to coerce the selection to `alias list` and get the POSIX path from an alias

```
tell application "Finder"
    set temp to selection as alias list
    repeat with i from 1 to length of temp
        set the_item to item i of temp           
        set the_result to POSIX path of the_item
        
        return the_result
    end repeat
end tell
```

`POSIX file` is only needed for the opposite, to get an HFS path or alias from a POSIX path.

If you want only the first item of the `selection` you don't need a loop but you have to check for *empty list*

```
tell application "Finder"
    set temp to selection as alias list
    if temp is not {} then            
       return POSIX path of item 1           
    end if
end tell
```

Comment: It would be a lot more advisable to `set temp to selection as alias list` especially if one is potentially looping through many selected files: _Finder_ file references are **always** going to be slower to generate, requiring increasing time and space as the depth within the directory tree increases. This is incurred in part a second time during iteration. `alias` objects are just a string file path paired with an `alias` object specifier, thus every reference, regardless of the file's location, occupies constant time and space. This also negates the need to coerce to `text`.

Answer (score 0):

I find this following, alternate AppleScript solution, as the choice I would use.

While Finder.app is front most, using the keyboard shortcut… option + command + c will copy the Posix Paths of the selected Finder items to the clipboard.

```
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "c" using {option down, command down}
```

Here is a little utility AppleScript I wrote which incorporates the action of retrieving the Posix Paths of the selected Finder items… if Finder is front most and there are selected items.

Ultimately, if Finder is not front most, if the selected text in the current document you are viewing is a Posix Path or HFS Path , it will reveal that item in Finder for you.

```
-- Add A Delay For Testing Purposes. 
-— Allowing You Time To Bring Application "Finder" Or Other Document To The Front
-— While Running This Code In Your Script Editing Application

delay 10

tell application "Finder" to set finderIsFrontmost to frontmost

if finderIsFrontmost then
    -- Copy Selected Files In Finder, As Path Names
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke "c" using {option down, command down}
else
    -- Copy Selected File Path Text From Current Doc In Frontmost App
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke "c" using {command down}
    delay 0.1
    -- The "-R" Reveals Copied File Path In Finder, Rather Than Opening If It's A Path To A File
    try
        do shell script "open -R " & quoted form of (the clipboard)
        delay 0.1
        tell application "Finder" to activate
        repeat until application "Finder" is frontmost
            delay 0.2
        end repeat
        delay 0.2
        tell application "System Events" to key code 124 using {command down, option down, control down}
    on error errMsg number errNum
        try
            do shell script "open -R " & quoted form of POSIX path of (the clipboard)
            delay 0.1
            tell application "Finder" to activate
            repeat until application "Finder" is frontmost
                delay 0.2
            end repeat
            delay 0.2
            tell application "System Events" to key code 124 using {command down, option down, control down}
        on error errMsg number errNum
            activate
            display alert errMsg message ¬
                "Either The File or Folder No Longer Exists" & linefeed & linefeed & "OR" & linefeed & linefeed & ¬
                "The Selected Text Contains Starting or Trailing White Spaces" & linefeed & linefeed & ¬
                "Please Make Sure Your Selected Text Has No Empty Spaces At The Beginning or End Of Your Selection" as critical buttons {"OK"} giving up after 20
        end try
    end try
end if
```

Comment: Opt-Cmd-C is a nifty shortcut for copying filepaths directly and it works with multiple files selected.